# Controlling a PWM'ed DC fan from 24v instead of 12V source

Tags: mosfet, dc, pwm

I have a tiny 12V which consumes ~0.07A and i was wondering if i can PWM the 12V fan with a 24V source at a 50% duty cycle through a ardunio and a mosfet. Would that work or fry the fan as the voltage is still 0 to 24v peak to peak.

Thanks,

Comment: When you operate some device outside of its intended range of voltage it is possible that it will fail very quickly. It is also possible that the design of the device is so conservative that it will work reliably for an indefinite time. With no specifications or information about the fan, all we can say is that your experience will be somewhere in that range.

Comment: It's a generic one but here is the link: https://www.ebay.com/itm/Quality-40x40x10mm-DC-12V-Brushless-Silent-Computer-PC-Case-Cooling-Cooler-Fans/142651248316?epid=15012782847&hash=item2136ad4ebc:g:wowAAOSwnlFaVXvw

Comment: That isn't really a datasheet. Links to vendors on ebay are usually not very helpful. You are on your own.

Comment: ah darn! Though what direction should i go towards? I mean resistor dividers or an LC filter cap

Comment: If you want to reduce power consumption get a dc/dc converter to get 12V from 24V. If you don't mind throwing away about a watt of power then use a linear 12V regulator with a heatsink.

Comment: but i am pretty sure i will loose my PWM capability

Comment: Why? This is no different than running the fan from a 12V supply in the first place. Why would PWM work at 24V but not 12V?

Comment: If the fan is only a DC motor (so, no smart driving ICs, just a coil) the voltage wont *fry* the fan. An overcurrent can overheat the coil causing it to "fry". (The voltage might cause a breakdown between two wires, but i think that chance is pretty low as the coil windings probably have good isolation). At 24V 50% PWM, a coil 'sees' about the same current as a coil at 12V 100% PWM.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Sorry, I meant that if i attach a dc/dc converter i'll loose my pre-existing PWM capability. The controller board(MKS Base) i am using is for 24V Fan which actually pwm's the output hence, controlling the speed of the 24V fan. But in my instance i needed to use a 12V (for a very complicated reason;clashing with the heat-bed etc.) Since i have control on the duty cycle i can set it to any % without any mods or anything physical.

Comment: @Huisman If so then i will give it ago.

Comment: You should have mentioned all of those details in your original question.

Comment: @Elliot Sometimes questions need to evolve. Your remarks helped clarifying.